# Azure DevOps - team member vs contributor?

Tags: azure-devops

Quick question - what's the difference between adding someone to the "Contributors" group versus adding that person as a team member? Will they get different permissions or see different things?

Certain features are configured on a team basis, via the "Team Configuration" page (e.g. default areas and iterations), so how does that affect someone who is only added to "Contributors" and is not made a team member?

Comment: Have you checked following replies? Are they helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone to access a project, they must be added to one of the default security groups or a custom group. Usually you add them to the Contributors group. For a quick look at what permissions are assigned to the default groups, see [Permissions and access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops).

Several Agile tools, like capacity planning, team alerts, and dashboard widgets are team-scoped. That is, they automatically reference the user accounts added as members of a team to support planning activities or sending alerts. To learn more, see [About teams and Agile tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-teams-and-settings?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 2):

All teams are included in Contributors automatically. The Contributors group enables basic access to the azure devops features (work items, source code, pipelines ...). If you add a new user to some team, that user will have additional features for work planning: participate in the team workload planning, can be assigned to tasks on scrum bards...